# Html.RenderPartial Throws System.InvalidException while trying to render a partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to render a partial view using `RenderPartial`, it keep throwing `System.InvalidOperationException`. Below is the folder structure that shows the Views folder.
[image]

I am accessing Simulation from Index and have tried below combination the error is same for all.

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("/Shared/Simulation");}
@{Html.RenderPartial("/Views/Shared/Simulation");}
@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/Simulation");}
```

I know it is some thing silly i am missing here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the full path, you need to include the file extension as well.

This should work.

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/Simulation.cshtml"); }
```

**Or** you can simply not use the full path, but just pass the view name

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("Simulation"); }
```

Razor view engine will look in the `~/Views/Shared` directory and render the view as the location follows the convention.